# Using concerns in controller to access a variable across all controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to create a variable inside `Controller concern` like below and use `@sidebar_menu_item` from other controller including `Application Controller`?

```
module Menu
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    class << self
        def add_sidebar_menu(top_level, menu_class, menu_items, expanded = false)
            @sidebar_menu_item ||= []
            @menu_items ||= []
            @sidebar_menu_item << [top_level, menu_class, @menu_items.concat(menu_items), expanded]
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: please elaborate on what you're trying to achieve as I don't think what you are suggesting is a proper way of doing things

Comment: Can you not put it into a helper instead of controller?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have it available in all controllers, the common pattern is to add it to the `ApplicationController` and share it via inheritance.

The method `add_sidebar_menu` raises the question that @SG86 asked. If it's just for the view layer, why are you not using a helper here?

Since you are talking about "sharing a variable" I assume, that you are also trying to store state in the controller. If that is the case, DONT DO IT. Use a session, cookie or the database for that.